# Global NPM package not installing

Tags: javascript, npm, command-line, npm-install, npx

I have written a command line utility in JS which can be used to backup data to IPFS.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-backup

When I am attempting to install it with `npm install -g ipfs-backup` I am getting an error which prevents the package from being installed.

The terminal is outputting the following:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path C:\Users\jwhit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ipfs-backup\node index.js
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\jwhit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ipfs-backup\node index.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

Comment: It looks like `ipfs-backup` is incompatible with Windows. The package is trying to call `chmod` which is a Linux command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that within my package.json file I had

```
"bin": {
    "ipfs-backup": "node index.js",
    "ipfs-restore": "node restore.js"
}
```

instead of

```
"bin": {
    "ipfs-backup": "./index.js",
    "ipfs-restore": "./restore.js"
}
```

It installs and functions correctly now.